# Re-using SVG gradient via CSS

Tags: css, angularjs, html, svg, gradient

So I know I can swap out a gradient fill on an svg with css, something like;

```
<svg width="100" height="50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style type="text/css">
    rect{fill:url(#GradientSwap1)}
  </style>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="GradientSwap1">
      <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F00" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#999" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <rect width="100" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

and using ng-class I can swap out more than one of these gradients, except I can only get it to work if I include the `<linearGradient>` in the defs embedded into each SVG.

My question is, and what I can't seem to figure out. Is there a way to pull these gradient defs out of the SVG and make them into a resource I can use in others? Like in the .NET / XAML world, it would be really easy for me to pull them out, throw them in a resource dictionary, and use the same ones all over the place for whatever I like.

So is there an html5/css3/angular approach to the same conundrum? The idea of having to have to multiple SVG's with potentially multiple of the same Gradient defs reiterated for every single one just sounds wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define the gradient once and then call it in the CSS to apply anywhere. You could apply to all svgs or give it a class.

```
<svg>
<defs>
<linearGradient id="GradientSwap1">
  <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F00"></stop>
  <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#999"></stop>
</linearGradient>
</defs>
```

```
<section>
<svg class="icon shape-facebook">
    <path d="M28.3,62V35.2h-5.5v-9.4h5.6v-7.7c0,0,0.3-9.8,9.8-9.8s9.5,0,9.5,0v9.2H42.1c0,0-2.699,0-2.699,2.7c0,2.7,0,5.8,0,5.8H48
l-1.1,9.4H39.6V62H28.3z"></path>
</svg>
<svg class="icon shape-heart" x="0" y="0">
        <path d="M35.645,59.413c0,0,26.949-19.601,26.949-34.12c0-16.752-22.049-22.047-26.949-1.674
    c-4.9-20.373-26.95-15.078-26.95,1.674C8.695,39.812,35.645,59.413,35.645,59.413z"></path>
</svg>
```

```
.shape-heart { fill: url('#GradientSwap1'); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6osyy5v/1/

Comment: Oh cool! +1 Except would this route make the Gradient only available within the same view that the svg referencing it is on? Or can plop the gradient somewhere to make it available globally like a class?

Comment: Yeah exactly - you'd need to put it somewhere that's global - right after the opening body tag or something like that otherwise it would only be available in the view it's actually in.

Comment: Oh right on, I wasn't making the index connection as the global resource point, like I have to translate things from the .net world still and it didn't click at first, thanks!